# Filter a list of object

Tags: list, kotlin, search, hashmap, searchview

Let say I have a list of objects:

```
data class Home(
    var id: String = "",
    var status: MutableMap<String, Double> = mutableMapOf(),
    var userName: String = "",
) 

var myList = listOf(
            Home("1", mutableMapOf("hello", 1.0), "firstUser"), 
            Home("2", mutableMapOf("hello", 2.0), "secondUser"), 
            Home("3", mutableMapOf("goodbye", 3.0), "thirdUser")
)
```

With this list, I want to implement a search view and I want to filter this list based on the map key or based on the username. For example, if I search for "hello" it will return a list with 2 objects inside:

```
listOf(Home("1", mutableMapOf("hello", 1.0), "firstUser"), 
       Home("2", mutableMapOf("hello", 2.0), "secondUser"))
```

I'm trying with no success the code below:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {

            myList.stream()
                .filter { p ->
                       p.userName.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())
                                .contains(newText.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())) ||
                       p.status.keys.contains(newText.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()))
                }
                .collect(Collectors.toList()) 

             adapter.submitList(myList)
        }
    })
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong, please?

EDIT: As @Joffrey said I modified my code so I can use Kotlin filters. I'm filtering by username and it's ok. When I try to filter myList by the map key, I have to insert the whole text to get any result, for example: "hello". At this point, I need to filter the list if the map's key contains a substring.

```
override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {

            val filteredList: List<Home> =
                myList.filter {
                    it.userName.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(newText.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())) ||
                            it.status.keys.contains(newText)
                }
            adapter.submitList(filteredList)

            return false
        }
```

Comment: You should generally avoid using Java streams in Kotlin, there are a ton of functions on collections in the stdlib that make stream+op+collect redundant (you can just use the operation directly). That said, neither Java stream nor Kotlin's filter will help here, since those return new collections and don't affect the original one. Basically your current `onQueryTextChange` implementation creates a new list and doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: I think generally the way you'd do this is to keep an original "full" list of all your data, and then have a separate "filtered" variable which is the currently displayed data. So you could reassign that ``filtered`` list with the results of your ``filter``, and then somehow notify the UI that it needs to update

Comment: @Joffrey I just updated my code. With the new list that is filtered I update a recycler view

Comment: @Erjon you're still not using the new list though. `myList` is not modified, the `collect()` call at the end of the stream chain *returns* a new list. You need to get the result of this expression to get the new list. As in `val filteredList = myList.stream().filter{...}.collect(...)`, or as I said earlier using Kotlin's filter: `val filteredList = myList.filter{...}`

Comment: @Joffrey ok I modified the code as you said. How can I filter it if the map contains a substring? For example, if I enter in the search view the text "hel" it should return a filtered list with 2 objects, cause it will find that there are 2 maps in the list that have a key "hello". Am I clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it like this, the function below will find every map in the list whose key contain the desired substring:

```
    infix fun <V> Map<String, V>.withKeyPart(keyPart: String): List<V> {
        return this.filter { it.key.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(keyPart) }
        .map { it.value }
}
```

Then to apply the search view I did like this:

```
override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {

            val filteredList: List<Home> =
                myList.filter {
                    it.userName.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(newText.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())) ||
                            it.status.withKeyPart(newText.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())).isNotEmpty()
                }

            adapter.myList(filteredList)

            return false
        }
```